# How to bind multiple commands

Tags: command-line, functions

We all have to use **ls |more**  and also some other commands.

So i just need info is there a way to bind multiple commands together like I want to bind **ls|more** together.So when i simply pass **ls** command it should display some data and wait for user to press key (space bar) to show rest of the data.

Is it possible in linux?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an alias to overwrite a command. In fact, this is already the case for `ls` as default this is aliased as `ls --color=auto`

Create a file called '~/.bash_aliases' and enter the following line

```
alias ls='ls | more'
```

Now when you type `ls` in your terminal, it will instead execute `ls | more`.

In this case it does has an issue with parameters. `ls /some/directory` will not work anymore because the parameters are applied to `more` instead of `ls` (`ls | more /some/directory` will be executed)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the ls command to still accept command-line switches you need to use a shell-script function, something like this should do:

```
ls() { command ls $@ | more; }
```

Put it into `~/.bashrc` to make it persistent.